# GNU GAS: Label is not relatively referenced

Tags: assembly, linker, nasm, boot, gnu-assembler

I am writing a little bootsector for learning purpose.

Here is boot.S

```
.code16
.text
    movw    $0xB800, %ax    /* 0xB000 is the text screen video memory */
    movw    %ax, %es       /* set it as the %es segment */

    movb    label, %al
    movb    %al, %es:0x0    /* screen[0] = 'A' */
    movb    $0x07, %es:0x1  /* white on black */
    jmp .

label:  
    .byte 'A

    .=510
    .byte 0x55
    .byte 0xAA
```

and here is the Makefile I use to compile it to a raw binary file

```
hdd.img: boot.S
    as $< -o boot.o
    ld --oformat binary -Ttext 0x7c00 boot.o -o hdd.img
```

I face the problem that the label is not relatively referenced: when loading the byte 'A', it uses the absolute address, say 0x7c14).

So I cannot relocate this bootsector at runtime (for example by copying it further in memory). It would be better if the label was simply referenced trough an offset from the current instruction.

Is it possible to do this ?

Comment: You can set `-Ttext` to `0` and make sure you start with a far jump to `0x7c0:0`. Then you can relocate your code to any segment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it is possible to relocate strings.

First of all, your `-Ttext 0x7C00` is correct. Do not change it.
At the beginning of your bootloader you should zero the segment registers (`%ds`, `%es`, `%fs`, `%gs` and `%ss`):

```
mov $0, %ax         // xor %ax, %ax would be more space efficient
mov %ax, %ds
mov %ax, %es
mov %ax, %fs
mov %ax, %gs
mov %ax, %ss
```

Next, you should set up a stack. Read: [osdev wiki about stacks](http://wiki.osdev.org/Stack)

Now to your question:
It is usual to address strings using [segmentation](http://wiki.osdev.org/Segmentation) in the form of `%ds:%si`. When relocating the bootloader, just change `%ds` properly.
Assuming you call your string `label`:

```
mov $label, %si     // Always prefix a label address with a $
```

You can get a character from a string using the `lodsb` instruction (**LO**a**D** **S**tring **B**yte, which automatically increments `%si` for you:

```
lodsb               // Character is stored in `%al` now
```

Another recommendation is not to address the video memory manually. Use [BIOS Interrupt 0x10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_10H).

Good luck with your bootloader!

Comment: If I keep ```-Ttext 0x7C00``` then ```%si``` will contain an absolute address such as ```0x7C14```. It will be a problem if I relocate the bootloader before ```0x7C00``` (say at ```0x6000```) no matter what ```%ds``` will be, no ? And if the relocation is after ```0x7C00``` then I'll have to compute in some way the difference between ```%si=0x7C14``` and my new relocation and set this difference as ```%ds``` ?

Comment: Yes, `%si` will contain an absolute address, but it should be possible to change `%ds` in a way that it is still pointed at a proper point. `%si` is *relative to* `%ds`.

Comment: It does not seem possible to relocate the bootloader before ```0x7C00``` because ```%si``` contains an already bigger address

Comment: In that case you have to set `%ds` to the segment containing your bootsector (0x7C00 >> 8 = 0x7C0 in the beginning, YOUR_ADDRESS >> 8 after the relocation). Copy the label's address to `%si` as usual, but subtract the address your bootloader begins at (see above). Then you can use segment-offset-addressing again.

Comment: I see. It seems less work to go with ```-Ttext=0``` no ? Any disadvantages ?

Comment: If you use -Ttext=0 your code expects to be located at 0x0000 which it is not. `jmp`s always jump to a fixed address and those addresses are hardcoded, you cannot change them. As soon as you use a `jmp` instruction, the program would jump to an address near 0x0000 and crash because there is no executable code in that region. You would have to do the far jump Jester was talking about in his comment and then you would still have to do the address math I mentioned.